# Compute $e^5$ to 2 decimal digits precision

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

> How to compute $e^5$ **without calculator** with 2 decimal digits precision?

I was thinking about Taylor series:
$e^x=\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$
, but it doesn't work.

(It's an interview question.)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: perhaps the fact that $e^x=lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ might help you

Comment: The Taylor series approach works. Find the first $n$ such that $5^n/n!<0.001$, then the $n-$ partial sum should give you an approximation with 2 decimal digits precision. You will find that $n= 16$ and then $$ 1+5+\frac{5^2}{2!}+\cdots + \frac{5^{16}}{16!}=148.4102103.$$ If you use a calculator you see that $e^5\simeq 148.4131591$. Thus, you have the desired approximation.

Comment: @mathematician By it doesn't work I meant I was not able to compute it with merely a pen. I understood Alonso Delfin demonstration, which is very helpful, but I think it's not obvious to compute the sum above during interview.

Comment: The Taylor series is about as well as you can do.  I would ask to clarify the question.  It is POSSIBLE to compute 16 terms of the Taylor series by hand.  All it is is basic arithmetic, just a lot of it.  Maybe this is what the interviewer meant.

Answer (score -1):

For starters, $e - s_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + ... < \frac{1}{(n+1)!} * \{1 + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + ...\} = \frac{1}{n!n}$, where $s_n$ is the nth partial sum of taylor series for $e$. See if you can use this to approximate $e^5$.

Answer (score -2):

You should trust the Taylor Series expansion more, it is simpler than you probably think. If $e^x$ is approximately $1+x+{x^2}/{2}+{x^3}/{6}+...$, we can approximate your expression as $1+5+12.5+125/6+625/24=18.5+(20+5/6)+(20+145/24)$ which is approximately $59.3+6$. The next term will be $3125/120$, after which is $15625/720$, after which is about $78000/5000$. The terms now become smaller and smaller as the factorial is being multiplied faster than 5 each term. Some rough guessing gives $65.3+27+22+16$. Perhaps we can guess the next terms can continue to get smaller such as $10,5,2$ and $1$. Adding these up yields $142.3$. If you feel lucky and throw in an extra $5$ for the infinite terms, you will be only $1.03$ lower than the actual value of $148.3362...$.

No calculator used until the very last "actual" figure.